# What song/theme is playing in episode 10 of season 2 in Tokyo Ghoul?

Tags: music, tokyo-ghoul

It's playing between 6:46 and 7:46. I've heard it multiple times in TG itself but couldn't find it on soundtrack, and many times elsewhere. I have a feeling it's somewhat popular

Answer (score -1):

The ending theme song is by queen bee and the song name is called HALF